# Where is the class view for a code behind file in VS 2005

Tags: asp.net, ide, visual-studio-2005, editor, class

I can't seem to find any of my code behind files in the class view tab. I can see other classes that I have added but none of the code behind files. Is there a reason for this? I am missing a setting or something? It is quite irritating trying to navigate my way through the code all the time.

I can see all the other classes just fine just not my code behind files.

Comment: What type of project is this? Website/Web application - Please clarify.

Comment: It is a website project.

Comment: For the record, this is the first Bounty question I've answered and I was concerned about this: http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/general/suggestions/117215-make-bounty-reputation-points-really-immune-to-daily-cap. Just making sure you're aware of this. ;-)

Comment: Sorry about that.I must admit things have been crazy at work and at home. It has been a whirlwind of work, eat and sleep. I didn't have much time to do my pet projects otherwise I would have been here. Sorry again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Class View is intended to provide a hierarchical view of the "symbols" defined in your project. For website projects, it will only list the referenced assemblies and any classes defined in App_code.

So, no, you aren't missing a setting. You're missing the point of the Class View window ! ;-) Maybe you should be looking in the Solution Explorer instead.

BTW, if you're having trouble navigating through code files, you should consider better organizing your files (in folders, for instance).

**Edit** (*after a Bounty has been placed on this question... drool!* ) :

---

Okay, I have VS 2005 SP1. I tried the following cases:

**a. Create New Website (VB or C#):**

The Class View window is blank until you add an `App_Code` folder. When added, the Class View window displays any classes added to the App_Code folder and the default Project references (System, System.Web, etc). It does not however display any Page code-behind classes.

**b. Create New Project -> Web -> ASP.NET WebApplication:**

The Class View window auto-populates with the Project references *and the Page code-behind classes.* This happens before I added any folder containing class files.

I am not sure if you are familiar with the ASP.NET Web Application Projects. If not, you need to have the Service Pack for VS 2005 installed. You can [get it here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=bb4a75ab-e2d4-4c96-b39d-37baf6b5b1dc&displaylang=en). Else, you can also install the Web Application Projects extension [directly](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/asp.net/aa336618.aspx).

Comment: I can see the classes, I just can't see their outline. I want to see a summary of the methods and variables in that class. Maybe that is what I should have said. Where is the class outline view???

Answer (score 1):

Don't be placing classes other than the class backing the page in code-behind.  Place all other code in a separate library project or at the very least in the App_Code folder.

Comment: I'd go further: don't use Website projects :)

Answer (score 1):

There should be a drop down menu right above the code. The left on is the classes in your open file and the right are members of the selected class.

A great way to navigate code in Visual Studio is with the right-click context menu's Go to Definition and Go to Declaration options.

You could also use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) on your assemblies to view the class/member hierarchy in a tree.

Comment: Hi. I found what you are talking about but that is rather irritating that I have to click a drop down. Is there no view that will display a complete list of variables and methods and clicking on it will take you to the place in the code. Similar to Eclipse's class outline view?

Comment: uriDium, I think you'll find what you are looking for with Reflector (it's free).

Answer (score 0):

VS 2008 improves the class view to what you want ... just saying.

Edit:  Nevermind, VS2005 should do what you want as well.  You can use the Object Browser as well.